# How to Preview Update Set Where Statement using MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, select, set

The query listed below works perfectly, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to convert it to a SELECT statement and preview the results. I know how to do it when SET and WHERE are used, but the JOIN statement is messing things up. I'd appreciate suggestions.

```
UPDATE WA.contacts c
  JOIN National.zips z
    ON c.zipcode = z.zipcode
   SET c.county = z.county
     , c.population = z.population
     , c.MA_Penetration = z.MA_Penetration
     , c.MA_Eligibles = z.MA_Eligibles
WHERE state = 'WA';
```

Comment: Thanks for tweaking the code. That makes using an alias a lot easier to understand. Something I've been wrestling with. I thought you always had to use AS when defining an alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use select and from

```
SELECT WA.contacts.county
  , National.zips.county
  , WA.contacts.population 
  , National.zips.population
  , WA.contacts.MA_Penetration 
  , National.zips.MA_Penetration
  , WA.contacts.MA_Eligibles 
  , National.zips.MA_Eligibles
FROM WA.contacts 
JOIN National.zips ON WA.contacts.zipcode = National.zips.zipcode
WHERE state = 'WA';
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an alias with the same code or would I have to use a different type of join?

Comment: @J.R.  your comment is not clear  to me ..  try explain better  or post a new specific question and  comment the link

Comment: Forgive me, my mind is fried today...The code you shared referenced the full database.table. However, @strawberry edited my original code and replaced it using aliases. I'd like to know if the code you shared above can ALSO incorporate aliases. Does that make sense or not?

Comment: @J.R.  . yes you can use table name  alias instead for full reference table  name ..  anyway   try and see what happen ..  (for me is the best way to learn  new thing) .